# Rails: Models design for a questionnaire application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I am very new to rails. I am currently working on this questionnaire application that open once every few months. Responses given by the users will be saved in the database for a few survey rounds and then be archived and deleted afterwards.

Administrators are able to view the responses, and modify the existing list of survey questions for the next round of survey. Administrators have a fixed user account under users table as I am currently using devise for authentication.

The part that I can't wrap my head around is how do I make it such that modifying questions can be possible without affecting the existing responses of past questionnaire rounds. I have thought of duplicating the questions but I'm not too sure on how to implement it due to my lack of my understanding of rails.

This is the current model I have came up with:

```
class Questionnaire < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :responses
end

class Response < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :questionnaires
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :questions
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :responses
end

class Users < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :responses
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zhenbin I would suggest  you to use something as act_as_versioned gem which keeps the version with every change in questions . So when ever new user gives survey latest question is pulled but when survey responses are pulled its pulled with its corresponding question

Comment: I have taken a look at the acts_as_versioned gem and it looks promising! I'll give that a try! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to modify questions? If you make the next round of surveys, just create new ones.

Furthermore, in your model you can't write `belongs_to` with pluralized names as you will get an error, refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association for more details.

Comment: It's because the same set of questions may be used in multiple rounds of survey.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *exporting* the questions and answers from the database after each survey round, that way you can always modify questions at a later date without having to worry about maintaining older question/answer relationships.

It could (for example) be exported to a database dump file, or a CSV file (marketing departments *love* those). Exporting to a file in ruby isn't very complicated, and I think you'll be able to find many resources for doing so. For a CSV export, for instance, check out the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Good luck!